# transfer learning TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pycharm, transfer-learning

I am having problems with my machine learning project. I made a CNN model and I want to test it out in a VGG16 VGG19 restnet models and other models this is the code that I think will make it work and i can just change vgg16 to other models. However, I keep getting this error:

> C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\pythonw.exe C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/rawr.py
>   Using TensorFlow backend.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/rawr.py", line 9, in 
>       my_new_model.add(vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))
>     File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras_applications\vgg16.py", line 97, in VGG16
>       data_format=backend.image_data_format(),
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_data_format'

Process finished with exit code 1

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import vgg16
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D

num_classes = 2
resnet_weights_path = 'C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/EDA'

my_new_model = Sequential()
my_new_model.add(vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))
my_new_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))


my_new_model.layers[0].trainable = False

my_new_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

image_size = 224
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)


train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/EDA',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/EDA',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        class_mode='categorical')

my_new_model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=3,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `vgg16.VGG16` instead of `vgg16`

Comment: this comes out SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/rawr.py", line 1
    from keras.applications import vgg16.VGG16
                                        ^

Comment: Sorry my answer was unclear, change your line 9 to `my_new_model.add(vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))`

Comment: and if you want to fix your import instead, use `from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16`

Comment: this came out when i fixed the import
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/rawr.py", line 9, in <module>
    my_new_model.add(vgg16.vgg16(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))
AttributeError: module 'keras_applications.vgg16' has no attribute 'vgg16'

Comment: It's `vgg16.VGG16` not `vgg16.vgg16` and you only need to apply only 1 change, either update `my_new_model.add(vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))` or change `from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16` and then `my_new_model.add(VGG16(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))`

Comment: ye i did and this came out OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/EDA', errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
how do i update the mynewmodel

Comment: and alot more error came out i tried some other stuff still nothing

Comment: Well that's a different question then, please show me the full stacktrace

Comment: so ye i edited the post and thats the error that i keep getting somehow putting lesser lowercase vgg16 gives me less errors XD